# Custom DefaultValue depending on the PC using Newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json.net, default-value

I have a JSON config value that could be different based on the number of processors, the memory size, the OS and so on.

The value itself can be calculated fairly easily at runtime, so I don't expect my users to have an entry for it in their own config.
But in some edge cases, the user could have their own value, (for test or load and so on).

I can set a default value, but that 'default' will not be the same for all machines:

```
...

[DefaultValue(8)]
[JsonProperty(DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Populate)]
public int EventsPerProcessor { get; protected set; }

...
```

Is there a way of knowing if the value was missing or not so I can calculate the correct 'default' value?

Or something like `[DefaultValue(MyCustomFunction(...) )]`?

NB: Of course, I could set my default value to `0`, (or even -ve), but then I would prefer to not assume that the user entered that value or not.

Comment: CustomJsonConverter is always an option.

Comment: Couldn't you just set the default value in the constructor for your containing object?

Comment: You mean not use `DefaultValue` at all?

Comment: @dbc I just tried and it does not work, (the value in the constructor is ignored).
Can you please show an example of what you mean.

Comment: Something like this?  https://dotnetfiddle.net/Da90bV

Comment: You could create a `CustomDefaultValueAttribute` which would override the `Value` property to provide a runtime value.

Comment: @dbc this is great thanks, I had forgoten the `[JsonProperty]`. Can you add it as an answer so I can give you the points.

Comment: @TylerBrinkley, sorrym, what is "`CustomDefaultValueAttribute`", is it a Newtonsoft attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the only effect of [`DefaultValueHandling.Populate`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_DefaultValueHandling.htm) is that

> Members with a default value but no JSON will be set to their default value when deserializing.

You could remove `[DefaultValue(...)]` and `DefaultValueHandling` entirely and, instead, initialize `EventsPerProcessor` in the class constructor:

```
public class RootObject
{
    static int CalculateDefaultEventsPerProcessor()
    {
        // Replace with calculated value
        return 12;
    }

    public RootObject()
    {
        EventsPerProcessor = CalculateDefaultEventsPerProcessor();
    }

    [JsonProperty]
    public int EventsPerProcessor { get; protected set; }
}
```

If `"EventsPerProcessor"` is not present in the JSON, the value calculated in the constructor will remain unchanged.

Note that, since `EventsPerProcessor` has a protected setter, it is still necessary to apply `[JsonProperty]`.

Sample fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Da90bV).